# Is there a standard protocol for isolating bacteriophages from biofilm?

Tags: biofilms, bacteriophage

We are planning to screen soil, water, and biofilm for mycobacteriophages, particularly the environments where the bacteria have been found in the past.

We have already isolated phages from soil but have had trouble finding a good protocol for isolating them from biofilm. [Nelson et al.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8025848/) isolated Mycobacteria by swabbing the biofilm of rocks. A Google Scholar search for [isolate bacteriophage from biofilm](https://isolate%20bacteriophage%20from%20biofilm) gives us results about the phages' ability to penetrate biofilm but not much about isolation.

We found [this paper](https://academic.oup.com/femsmicrobes/article/doi/10.1093/femsmc/xtab003/6204716), which described a protocol for extracting phages from skin swabs, which we could try to extrapolate to biofilm swabs.

Is there a paper that describes phage isolation from biofilms on hard surfaces such as rocks and human-built environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A 2019 paper in *Viruses*](https://www.mdpi.com/1999-4915/11/8/749) used sonication to monitor the phage titer of *P. aeruginosa* biofilms associated with "stainless steel coupons".

> In order to better understand the repartition of phages after the treatments, samples were taken to determine the quantity of planktonic viruses in the mineral minimum medium around stainless steel coupons, but also to estimate the amount that was biofilm-associated. In the first case, samples were collected directly on the liquid medium of the jar after 14 h of phage activity and titered by following the previously detailed protocol. In the second case, at the end of treatment, the liquid medium around the coupons was discarded and replaced by the same volume of medium. The biofilm was then resuspended by sonication (Figure 1), allowing the sampling and titering of biofilm-associated phages.
> Sonication of controls was assessed by adding the same phage titers in each jar (3 × 10<sup>10</sup> PFU/jar). The titer was then evaluated by the spot test method when jars had not been sonicated and after 1, 3, and 5 min of sonication.

Unfortunately, their methods include neither the frequency of sonication nor the specific sonicator used.

[A 2016 paper in *Frontiers in Microbiology*](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fmicb.2016.01024/full) investigating phage mitigation of catheter-associated biofilms found that sonication reduces the viability of phage particles. Anecdotally, vigorous vortexing is sufficient to break the tails off of Myoviridae and Siphoviridae phages when making TEM preps, so it's not surprising that sonication has an effect on phage infectivity. However, if your goal is phage discovery and not phage titer determination, I wouldn't worry too much about viability -- *some* phage will survive the sonication process.

Riffing on the insights from these papers, here's a simple protocol on which you can build:

1. Scrape biofilms from hard surfaces using a sterilized razor blade and (carefully!) transfer the biofilm to a conical tube using a sterile toothpick or pipette tip.
2. Wash the biofilm in [phage buffer](https://www.protocols.io/view/Phage-Buffer-rm7vzn12vx1w/v1) or similar medium by repeated centrifugation. This will help to remove phage that aren't strongly associated with / contained within the biofilm.
3. Add the appropriate volume of fresh buffer for sonication. Note that buffer volume is an important parameter in efficiency of sonication (see [Figure 1 of this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4731078/)).
4. Sonicate! If you don't have access to an [ultrasonic probe homogenizer](https://web.archive.org/web/20210513095856/https://www.biologics-inc.com/cell-disrupter.html), water-bath sonicators are [relatively affordable](https://www.thomassci.com/scientific-supplies/Bath-Sonicator) and will probably work for your purposes.
5. Use the sonicated sample as input for your favorite [phage enrichment protocol](https://seaphages.org/video/50/).

Happy hunting!